# Java Splash Argument using file inside Jar

Tags: java, splash-screen, jvm-arguments

So I have a Splash.png file inside a package. I want to pass the -splash:splash.png argument when running the jar file but I want the path to be directed to an internal package in the jar not externally where the jar is actually running

for example I have a package called res but when I do 
`-splash:res/splash.png` it wont show the splash

when I do `-splash:splash.png` and have the png file laying outside the jar file it shows the splash screen no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When inside the jar it appears that it must be specified through the manifest in the runnable jar.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: <class name>
SplashScreen-Image: <image name>
```

See "How to Use a JAR File to Display Splash Screen" section of   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html

Answer (score 0):

/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

JAR: image in a package?

- *package* theshow.jimmylandstudios.gui
- *img-path* theshow/jimmylandstudios/gui

  ```
  Manifest-Version: 1.0
  Class-Path: .
  Main-Class: theshow.jimmylandstudios.gui.GUI
  SplashScreen-Image: theshow/jimmylandstudios/gui/images/splash.png
  ```

Comment: is this actually an answer? please provide more details how to fix and why this will fix.

Comment: Its a working example. Here's how  I do the Edit. 1st: Open runnable Jar (w/ archive manager [Engrampa]). 2nd: Open /META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (w/ text editor [pluma]). 3rd:  Add line "SplashScreen-Image: relative/path/to.png" save tmp file, then the archive manager will ask to update the JAR; [yes]. Thats one way to do this on a Debian desktop OS.